# How to use regex to extract nested patterns

Tags: regex, nested

Hi I'm struggling with some regex

I've got a string like this:

```
a:b||c:{d:e||f:g}||h:i
```

basically name value pairings. I want to be able to parse out the pairings so I get:

```
a:b
c:{d:e||f:g}
h:i
```

then I can further parse the pairings contained in { } if required
It is the nesting that is making me scratch my head.  Any regex experts out there that can give me a hand?

thanks,

Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any limit on the depth of nesting in your strings ?  If not your language is not regular and regular expressions are the wrong tool -- as you are discovering already.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, I've restructured/simplified my information so it is easier to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

Arbitrarily nested patterns is irregular. So, no, you can't just use regex to parse this.